# Play Framework - put file at the same level of topLevelRoot with activator dist

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

When I zip my application with "activator dist" I would put the appspec.yml (AWS Codedeploy config file) at the same level of the topLevelDirectory in the zip file. So, if my project name is "test", I would get a zip file test-1.0.0.zip with this structure:

> |->appspec.yml 
>   |-> test
>
> > |-> bin 
> >      |-> conf 
> >      |-> lib 
> >      |-> share

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your issue by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution, so I am sharing it here in case someone else wants to do the same. I am having a multiproject repository, so it should be tuned a bit for simple projects:

lazy val stuff = (project in file("stuff"))
    .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin, JavaAppPackaging, LauncherJarPlugin)
    .settings(
        name := "stuff",
        topLevelDirectory := None,
        commonSettings
    )